# Can browsers SEND compressed XHR requests (eg, POST) with deflate or gzip?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, xmlhttprequest

We all know browsers can receive compressed data with the right content-encoding header.

Can browsers also SEND compressed data and take care of doing either gzip or deflate compression?

EG: Lets say I have a large text body I want to send via a POST. Can the browser compress that for me automatically when I am using the fetch or XHR APIs?

Comment: There are libraries to zip up stuff

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compressing HTTP Post Data sent from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031968/compressing-http-post-data-sent-from-browser)