# Compress file before upload

Tags: javascript, html, compression, filereader

Given requirements to handle the upload of large files (up to 1GB so far), would it be an advantage to compress the file client-side before upload? For example, using a library such as  [zip.js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo1.html)

The issue we are having now is the user initiates the file upload, and with large files has to wait anywhere up to 30mn for it to complete, and ties up the screen during this time.

As of now, our uploads are handled server side via IAsyncUpload (C#, with telerik controls).

Would it be faster to implement something [File Reader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) based for this? Will compression on upload save the user some hassle?

Comment: depends on the data your user is uploading... if it already has some compression (or the distribution is near uniform), another compression will just use CPU time... anyway, maybe this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031968/compressing-http-post-data-sent-from-browser

Comment: @LEo Excel documents, mainly. No images.